# When will we know the results of the recent elections for moderators?

Tags: support, status-completed, moderators, election

Recently, I exercised my civic SO duty and voted three choices for moderators.

1. Have the 2011 election results been tallied?
2. Will we be notified about the winners and, if so, how?

One suggestion: The pop up bar that we see from time to time could point to announcements. An e-mail notice works for me, too.

Preferable, for me, any results announcement should be proactive in some way.

Comment: I don't understand why this is being downvoted. There was a post on meta, but there are probably many voters who don't read meta frequently enough to have seen it.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Probably "One suggestion: The pop up bar that we see from time to time could point to announcements. An e-mail notice works for me, too.". I didn't downvote it, but yet another pop up about the election is probably bad; an e-mail is far worse

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The results were posted in [November 2011 Community Moderator Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113294/november-2011-community-moderator-election-results):

> Well, [it's finally over.](https://stackoverflow.com/election) Our
>   year-end excuse for navel-gazing has come to an end, with four new
>   moderators fresh from the turkey-fryer and ready to volunteer their
>   formerly-precious free time in service to the users of Stack Overflow:
>
> [image: boltclock] [image: NullUserException] [image: casperone]
>   [image: anna-lear]
>
> Let's take a moment to give a hearty meta-welcome to our new
>   moderators, before they get turned loose on the site and destroy us
>   all...
>
> I also wish to announce that veteran moderators [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) and
>   [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo) are hanging up their mod-hats. Moderating a site the size
>   of Stack Overflow can be a thankless job at times, so please join me
>   now in thanking them both for their service, and wishing them all the
>   best as they rejoin the esteemed ranks of Stack Exchange experts.
>
> <sub><sup>*Now back to your regularly-scheduled Meta
>   Madness...*</sup></sub>

I don't think that there was any notification. There are probably many voters who don't read meta frequently enough to have seen the announcement; some notification on SO itself might be appropriate.

Comment: thank you.  i hope next year the results are announced ... for me, the pop up is best; the e-mail second best, and no notication of results is the worst.  while i'm on SO far less frequently than many other members, for me, given that i took the time to read each candidate's statement and decide who would be my first, second, and third choice for moderator, imho, it's fair to expect to be notified as soon as the results are available. g.